# Error while trying to scrape two pages at the same time - Python, bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the links of some movies from a (main) website and after that, to scrape the contents from those links.

In the code below, I have tried to do it with only one link, but eventually, I will use a loop for all of them.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

def make_soup(url):
    # opening up connection, grabbing the page
    source = urlopen(url).read()

    # opening up connection, grabbing the page
    page_soup = soup(source, "lxml")

    return page_soup


soup = make_soup('https://letterboxd.com/top10ner/list/2020-edition-top10ners-1001-greatest-movies/')

#### code for grabbing the links
#### link = first_link

my_url = str(link)

new_soup = make_soup(my_url)

new_cont = new_soup.find('div', {'id':'content'})
```

And I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/calinap/PycharmProjects/WebScraping/letterboxd_scrape.py", line 34, in 
>       new_cont = new_soup.find('div', {'id':'content'})
>     File "/Users/calinap/PycharmProjects/WebScraping/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2127, in **getattr**
>       raise AttributeError(
>   AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Answer (score 0):

this probably isn't necessary 
`my_url = "'" + str(link) + "'"`

just do `my_url = str(link)`

Ok. I think I know what's going on - you are trying to open a page which is rendered with JS. Some pages, such as facebook - extensively use this method. Instead of sending you a result page, which you can parse and extract data from, they are sending you JavaScript code, which needs to be executed to generate page with the results. If you definitely need to to have this logic - you would need to use headless browser, such as `chromium`.

you would need to replace this:

```
source = urlopen(url).read()
```

with something linke this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
source = driver.get(url)
```

have a look here:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: This is what i get if i print the soup: [ ]. No errors though

Comment: give me an example of a link

Comment: I have tested the link separately and it is working

Comment: perhaps links are missing `https://` -- if so, then you should add it - your browser is smart enough to do it automatically, your BeautifulSoup4 isn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211700/discussion-between-summerbye-and-avloss).